# How to work with MVC5 and EF6 using bootstrap - jquery - customize my textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I want to know how to as would be add more attribute for a text box html element

Eg.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DBFIELDFROMTABLE, "CustomTemplate", new { @class = "form-control"})
```

i want add Maxlength

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DBFIELDFROMTABLE, "CustomTemplate", new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Comment: Did the below answer help you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just add another item to the Html Attributes object. You can add as many as you like separated by command.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DBFIELDFROMTABLE, "CustomTemplate", new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "10"})
```